# Question score wraps unexpectedly when greater than 99 in related questions list

Tags: bug, design

When a question has a score of over 99, it looks wrong in Safari v7.0.3 on OS X when presented in the related/linked questions list in the sidebar:

[image: Screenshot of the issue showing a question with score "123" wrapped over two lines].

This issue can be relatively successfully solved by changing the `width` declaration for `.answer-votes` to `min-width`, which makes the above answer look like this instead:

[image: A screenshot of the same item with the CSS changed as per my recommendations above]

Comment: Just came across this bug. Does seem to be limited to Safari, looks fine on Firefox.

Comment: @andrewb It will depend somewhat on the exact score of the answer (if it's 111 it will probably fit, but 288 not so much)